# Is it possible to launch an Flutter app on dismissing notification?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, notifications, awesome-notifications

I have an taxi app **made with Flutter**, where notifications are sent for drivers to accept / reject an ride... Sometimes, drivers unknowingly dismiss the notifications and thereby they don't open the app to either accept or reject the ride...

Notification on tap opens the app, but is it possible to launch app on dismissing the notification??

Answer (score 0):

Both Android and iOS expose APIs that support this:

Android: [`Notification.Builder#setDeleteIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setDeleteIntent(android.app.PendingIntent))

iOS: [`UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationdismissactionidentifier)

However, it seems that `flutter_local_notifications` plugin does not really support it (see https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/74) so you may need to write some native code to handle this case.

Comment: I'm using Awesome Notifications in my Flutter app

Comment: Remember to add all relevant information to your question. It seems that `awesome_notifications` does not support these APIs either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach.

Whenever this type of notification is received in your app just open a screen in your app just like video/audio call feature in social apps.